# Problem trying to group data and plot ggplot histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2, reshape2

I have a csv file which contains these three columns of data entries:

```
before           after             Style             
14                 20              group
2                  0               alone
17                 17              alone
4                  2               group
6                  3               group
```

I managed to plot a ggplot histogram that compares before and after values.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
responses = read.csv("dataframe.csv")

responses$exercise_style <- as.factor(responses$exercise_style)
responses$Exercise_before = as.numeric(as.character(responses$Exercise_before))
responses$Exercise_after = as.numeric(as.character(responses$Exercise_after))

before = responses$Exercise_before
after = responses$Exercise_after

Style = responses$exercise_style

frame1 = data.frame(before,after,hours)
frame2 = melt(frame1,id.vars = 'hours')

plotting = ggplot(frame2,aes(x = hours, y = value, fill = variable))

Bars = geom_bar(stat="identity",position="dodge")

plotting + Bars
```

[image]
But the problem is that it only compares "before-after" values, are there any ways to also take "style" factor into consideration and group data with it?

Comment: You use a variable called `hours`, but haven't told us what that is

Comment: hours = c(1:25)

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to represent 3 dimensional data. Only way I can think of is since you only have 2 styles you can use different color groups for different styles. For example **alone** could use blue and cyan and **group** could use red and yellow. Just an opinion